# Rotating image of same URL does not update without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the below code to rotate 3 images which works correctly.

The issue I have is that image1.png changes frequently and the browser will not refresh the image. Refreshing the page is not an option.

I'm aware that I can add a time variable to the end of the filename such as `image1.png?41234134` (for example) but how can I do this without refreshing the page? (I'm familiar with PHP and can get a new timestamp on page load, but I'm not sure how todo this in Javascript or maybe jquery without reloading the page to get the new value).

```
<?php
echo ' 
<div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" width="480" height="480" src="' . $absolute_path . '/image1.png" class="rotating-item" />
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" width="480" height="480" src="' . $absolute_path . '/image2.png" class="rotating-item" />
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" width="480" height="480" src="' . $absolute_path . '/screen_600x600.png" class="rotating-item" />
</div>';
?>
```

The page loads also some Javascript to do the image rotation:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    var InfiniteRotator = 
    {
        init: function()
        {
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;
            var itemInterval = 10000;
            var fadeTime = 1000;
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;
            var currentItem = 0;
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                    currentItem = 0;
                }else{
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);
            }, itemInterval);   
        }   
    };
    InfiniteRotator.init();
});
```

Comment: You mean the first image is going to refresh *after* a user has loaded the page? And you want to keep showing the latest image? You can add another interval and run something like `document.querySelector("#rotating-item-wrapper img").src = "/absolute/path/image1.png?" + Math.random();` inside.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your reply. The page loads only once and stays on users screen. The image rotation script will cycle through all three images correctly (as it does now) but image1.png may have changed on the server and I need it to pick up the new image1.png (without a page refresh).

Comment: @ChrisGThanks for the edit and further info. I have no idea how to do that in javascript, I can do PHP but don't know javascript at all, cold you help further? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same query string "cache-busting" trick in JavaScript. You just need to create a new image object and assign it the source of your image, with a random query string value attached:

```
var newImage = new Image(300, 300);
var randomVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000));
newImage.src = `picture.jpg?${randomVal}`;
```

This will cause the browser to re-fetch that image. You can then replace your existing image or add it to the page somewhere, e.g.:

```
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @ChrisG and other's advice, appending a random query field to the image should do the trick of reloading the image as opposed to from cache. I modified your code by storing the relevant image names to an array and inserted a preloader between fade-in/fade-out cycles.

```js
var absolute_path = '<?php echo $absolute_path; ?>';
var images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "screen_600x600.png"];


$(document).ready(function() {

  // init image src
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $('.image-holder').eq(i).attr("src", absolute_path + "/" + images[i] + "?" + (new Date().getTime()));
  }


  // the rest 

  var InfiniteRotator = {
    init: function() {
      var initialFadeIn = 1000;
      var itemInterval = 10000;
      var fadeTime = 1000;
      var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;
      var currentItem = 0;
      $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

      var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {

        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

        if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
          currentItem = 0;
        } else {
          currentItem++;
        }

        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        // prefetch next image

        var prefetchItem = (currentItem + 1) % numberOfItems;
        $('.rotating-item').eq(prefetchItem).attr("src", absolute_path + "/" + images[prefetchItem] + "?" + (new Date().getTime()));

      }, itemInterval);
    }
  };
  InfiniteRotator.init();
});
```

```css
.image-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
  <img class="image-holder rotating-item" />
  <img class="image-holder rotating-item" />
  <img class="image-holder rotating-item" />
</div>
```